# calculus and exponential functions

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

$0\leq t\leq3$, $t$ (measured in hours)

$$G_1(t)=4e^{t/2}$$ Diabetic
$$G_2(t)=8-4e^{-t/2}$$ Non diabetic-

Relating to the question but the whole question isn't important, there are six parts and I cant seem to get two of them right.

d) When does the diabetic patient have a glucose level of $10$? (G corresponds to glucose levels)
My working out:

$$G_1(t)=4e^{t/2}$$
Let $G_1=10$
$$10=4e^{t/2}$$
$$10/4=e^(t/2)$$
$$ln(10/4)=t/2$$
$$t= 2ln(10/4)$$
$$t \approx 1.8$$ (1 hour and 80 min so becomes two hours etc) 
however this isn't the answer :( it is actually 1 hour and 50 minutes!

f) At which point in the experiment has the diabetic patient twice the glucose levels of the non diabetic patient?

I know $$2G_1=G_2$$
$$2(4e^{t/2})=8-4e^{-t/2}$$

BUT i CANT SEEM TO FIND $t$

help please, thankyou in advance!

Comment: Note that $1.8$ hours is actually about 1 hour and 50 minutes, not 1 hour and 80 minutes.

Comment: @boywholived There is no downvote on this question currently.

Comment: Also recommended reading: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I dont know what I did wrong..... down vote?

Comment: @ Alex bexker Also are you saying i am getting the right answer? or are you saying close enough.

Comment: @Unistudent9 I haven't checked your work, just pointing out that you're converting the time incorrectly, which *may* be the source of your error.

Comment: @ Alex becker THANKS~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part $1$ is good. See the comment of Alex Becker. $1.8$ hours is one hour and $0.8$ of another hour which consists of $60$ minutes. $0.8$ of $60$ is $0.8 \cdot 60 = 48$. Therefore $1.8$ hours is $1$ hour and $48$ minutes.

Part $2$

EDIT:
You must set (!) 
$$
G_1 = 2G_2
$$
From
$$
4e^{\frac{t}2} = 2(8 - 4e^{\frac{-t}2})
$$
you get, by multiplying the equation by $e^{\frac{t}2}$,
$$
4e^t = 16 e^{\frac{t}2} - 8 
$$
or
$$
e^t - 4e^{\frac{t}2} + 2 = 0
$$
Now substitue $e^{\frac{t}2} = x$ and use $ (e^{\frac{t}2})^2 =e^{\frac{t}2} \cdot e^{\frac{t}2} = e^t$ to get 
$$
x^2 -4x + 2 =0
$$
Tell me if you can proceed from here. It looks like no real solution is there.

If we analyse a bit the function for diabetic patient we can see that it is exactly $4$ at $t=0$ and monotonically increases to $4e^{\frac32}=17.93$ at $t=3$.

On the other hand, the function for non-diabetic patient is exactly $4$ at $t=0$ and monotonically increases to $8-4e^{-\frac32}=7.11$ at $t=3$.

Comment: I see, however isnt t meant to be greater or equal to one when I punch your answer into the calculator i get a negative :( or am I doing it wrong? not trying to hate on your answer or anything quite happy you answered :)

Comment: Just continue studying and things will get much easier. Good luck

Comment: @Unistudent9  look what we overlooked! I edited the answer

Comment: I see thanks again! very helpful